# Graphing the graph of y=f(x) for $\tan(f(x))=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$ given that $f(0)=\pi$

Tags: graphing-functions

I would like to know what the graph of $\tan(f(x))=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$ given that $f(0)=\pi$ looks like.

**My attemt**

$\tan(f(x))=\tan(f(x)+k\pi)$ for some intiger $k$. It follows that $f(x)=\arctan{\frac{x}{1-x^2}}-k\pi$ . Using the initial condition we find$k=-1$ and thus $f(x)=\arctan{\frac{x}{1-x^2}}+\pi$ when I graphed this and checked with desmos this does not look like $\tan(f(x))=\tan(f(x)+k\pi)$ as the limits for $x\to \infty$ differ. In my case as $x\to\infty$,  $f(x)$  tends to $\pi$ but in the solution it tends to $2\pi$.

**My Graph**

[image]

**Answer graph**

[image]

Could someone explain to me what I have done wrong?

**Edit** I should add that we were told that we may assume that $f(x)$ is continues at +/- 1. Maybe this was they way of telling is that we need to make it look continius?

Comment: All the equations here contain only one variable, hence cannot be drawn in the plane. Did you mean to set $f(x)=y$?

Comment: i believe that is what was meant here

Comment: @Allawonder yes sorry, in the question we were told to graph $y=h(x)$ and in writing this on stack exchange I used $f(x)$ instead. In essence, I want to find the graph of $y=f(x)$. Sorry for the confusion, let me know if that makes it clearer

Comment: @MathsWizzard So you want to draw the curve $$\tan y=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$$?

Comment: @Allawonder yes given that $y=\pi$ at $x=0$

Comment: To deduce some properties, check what happens if you perform $x\mapsto -x$ or $y\mapsto -y.$ Then consider $x$ as a function of $y.$ Then $y$ as a function of $f.$ This gives you a general picture.

Comment: I think your problem is related to the fact, that initial conditions only define a function uniquely if the function is defined on an interval. That means that the equation $f(x)=arctan(\frac{x}{1-x^2}) + \pi$ only holds for $x\in (-1,1)$. The value of $k$ might differ on both $(-\infty,-1)$ and $(1,\infty)$. But if you know for instance that $f$ should be continuous, then you could solve for the right values of $k$ on those intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true, that for any $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{-1,1\}$ there must exist a $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, such that $f(x) = \arctan(\frac{x}{1-x^2})+k\pi$, but we cannot simply assume that the same $k$ holds for all $x$.

If we have further information, such as the information that $f$ is continuous on $(-\infty, -1)\cup (-1,1)\cup (1,\infty)$, then we must have a fixed constant on each interval, meaning that
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \arctan(\frac{x}{1-x^2}) + k_1\pi &,\text{for } x\in (-\infty,-1) \\
 \arctan(\frac{x}{1-x^2}) + k_2\pi &,\text{for } x\in (-1,1) \\
\arctan(\frac{x}{1-x^2}) + k_3\pi &,\text{for } x\in (1,\infty) \end{cases}$$
And as you have already mentioned the initial condition $f(0)=\pi$ implies that $k_2=1$.

Now if we want to extend $f$ to a function on the entire real line in a way, such that it is continuous, then we must have
$$f(-1) = \lim_{x\:\uparrow \: -1}\arctan(\frac{x}{1-x^2}) +k_1 \pi = \lim_{x\:\downarrow \:-1} \arctan(\frac{x}{1-x^2}) + \pi$$
and
$$f(1) = \lim_{x\:\uparrow \: 1}\arctan(\frac{x}{1-x^2}) + \pi = \lim_{x\:\downarrow \: 1} \arctan(\frac{x}{1-x^2}) + k_3\pi$$
where $\lim_{x \: \uparrow a}$ and $\lim_{x \: \downarrow \: a}$ denotes left and right limits respectively. Using that, $\lim_{y\rightarrow -\infty}\arctan(y) = -\pi/2$ and $\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \arctan(y) = \pi/2$ we find that $f(-1) = \frac12 \pi$ and $f(1) = \frac{3}{2} \pi$ and therefore $k_1 = 0$ and $k_3 = 2$, thus finally we get that

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \arctan(\frac{x}{1-x^2})  &,\text{for } x\in (-\infty,-1) \\
 \frac12 \pi  &,\text{for } x=-1 \\
 \arctan(\frac{x}{1-x^2}) + \pi &,\text{for } x\in (-1,1) \\
 \frac32 \pi  &,\text{for } x=1 \\
\arctan(\frac{x}{1-x^2}) + 2\pi &,\text{for } x\in (1,\infty) \end{cases}$$